# Can Blender import videos with transparent background?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, transparency

I have video with transparent background which I wanna import to Blender sequencer. I've checked in my browser that my video is 100% has transparent background. When I add it to sequencer in blender it has black background.
When I export it using WebM I also get black background on time when transparent video should be placed but transparent where I place some transparent pngs. So transparency is active but seems blender can't import transparent videos.

This video imports to Davinci Resolve without any problem.

What do you think?

```
Blender 2.93.0a
My video's format: WebM, libvpx-vp9.
Ubuntu Linux.
```

Comment: I would say you will have to convert webm to PNG sequence. There exists a bunch of free online convertors or if you have FFMPEG installed use command ffmpeg -vcodec libvpx -i yourvideo.webm frames/%04d.png ... Sure change "yourvideo" to name of your file.

Comment: Did you switch the compositing in the strip sidebar to alpha over?

Comment: @tintwotin, yes. Finally I found there's some transparent format that Blender supports for transparency, it's: `-vcodec prores_ks -pix_fmt yuva444p10le -profile:v 4444`

Comment: Could you explain what you mean a bit more? You're converting the video using FFMPEG and these are settings? - could you say exactly where you are entering these settings. I'm wondering too if Handbrake could do the same for processing video for this task.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

However I found some transparent format that Blender supports for transparency, it should be reencoded like this:

```
ffmpeg -i in.webm -vcodec prores_ks -pix_fmt yuva444p10le -profile:v 4444 out.mov
```

"Blend"-option should be set to "Alpha Over" in the N-panel of the strip.